# How can I detect file change from outside in VSCode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a file `foo.txt` and open it with my Custom Editor Extension.
When my extension edit it, I can know the change by fire `onDidChangeDocument` Event.
But how can I know change from outside?
For example, I should update my web-view when some other program edit `foo.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemWatcher).

Also read: [FileSystemProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider).